# display: incline-block doesn't work: divs are on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position divs side by side in several rows (so that they automatically went to the next row once there's no space in the previous row):

**Fiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/avuc1yze/

What I want to achive:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

**html**:

```
<div id="dogs">
    <div class="dog">
        <p>dog</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dog">
        <p>dog</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dog">
        <p>dog</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dog">
        <p>dog</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dog">
        <p>dog</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
#dogs  {
  display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.dog  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the `.dog` need to be inline-block not the `#dogs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your CSS add `display: inline-block;` on `.dog`

```
.dog  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/u8w45xg9/1/